# Interaction of generics, subclassing, and method override in Java

Tags: java

If I have a generic base class:

```
public class BaseExample<T> {        
   public void doTheThing(T value) {...}
}
```

And I want to subclass it such that I can doTheThing for different types:

```
public class SubExample extends BaseExample {
   public void doTheThing(String value) { ... }
   public void doTheThing(Integer value) { ... }
}
```

Is there a way to do this better than:

```
public class SubExample<T> extends BaseExample<T> {
   @Override
   public void doTheThing(T value) {
        if (value instanceof String) {
           doTheThing((String) value); 
        } else if (value instanceof Integer) {
           doTheThing((Integer) value);
        } else {
           dontDoTheThing();
        }
   }
   public void doTheThing(String value) { ... }
   public void doTheThing(Integer value) { ... }
}
```

Note:  I expect this to be called via:

```
BaseExample example = new SubExample()
example.doTheThing("Hello world");
```

Also note that in my case the Base class is in a library that I have no control over, so I cannot modify the base class.

[edit] In response to the question why would I want this?

A little difficult to describe without a lot more context, but I'll try.

This is part of an overall processing pipeline in which different instances of subclasses of BaseExample are instantiated to handle responses for different types of objects.  As objects are passed in, the pipeline passes those objects down to the subclasses in the processing chain.  The expectation of the framework is that each subclass instance only handles one type of object, but in my example I need to be able to handle different types within one instance and the processing for those types is markedly different.

Comment: In Java we call these "generics" not "templates", the two are somewhat different.

Comment: Java does not support multiple inheritance. Even if `BaseExample` were an `interface`, you cannot inherit the same generic `interface` twice, due to type erasure. Furthermore `SubExample extends BaseExample<T>` won't compile, as you must inherit with a concrete type. Finally `BaseExample example = new SubExample()` is a raw type.

Comment: In short - you cannot do anything of what you want; and its not entirely clear why you would want to.

Comment: Updated to fix the compilation issue and use the correct terminology around generics.

Comment: Now your `SubExample` extends the raw type `BaseExample`. This does compile but is very bad.

Comment: Yes... not at all good form, which is why I was asking the question.  Alternate would be `class SubExample<Object>`, but that doesn't really improve matters.

Comment: Plus checking the type in a chain like you are is considered an anit-pattern.  What is your actual goal here?

Comment: This smells a lot like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me.